# Double if value statements jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to have 2 if value statements with jQuery?
Right now it is like if you select 20 Fruit then a div will show.

This is my html:

```
<select name="bestemming" id="CoachTravel" class="form-control select" >
<option value="10 Glasses" >10 Glasses</option>
<option value="20 Fruit" >20 Fruit</option>
<option value="30 Cars" >30 Cars</option>
</select>
```

And my jQuery:

```
$('#venetie').hide(); 

 $('#CoachTravel').change(function(){
        if($('#CoachTravel').val() == '20 Fruit' ) {
            $('#venetie').show(); 
        } else {
            $('#venetie').hide(); 
        } 
    });
```

So if you will select 20 Fruit, then the div #venetie will show.
But i want that if you also select 30 Cars then div #venetie will also show.

I have tried this:

```
 $('#CoachTravel').change(function(){
        if($('#CoachTravel').val() == '20 Fruit', '30 Cars' ) {
            $('#venetie').show(); 
        } else {
            $('#venetie').hide(); 
        } 
    });
```

But that is now working for me, can someone please help me out?
Here is a Jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/1Lfgrwjj/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can use or operator in if condition:

```
var coachTravel = $('#CoachTravel').val();
if( coachTravel == '20 Fruit' ||  coachTravel =='30 Cars' ) {
```

also you can narrow down your code using condition in toggle function to make show hide decision:

```
$('#CoachTravel').change(function(){
   var coachTravel = $('#CoachTravel').val();
   $('#venetie').toggle(coachTravel == '20 Fruit' ||  coachTravel =='30 Cars'); 
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1uqgk4em/)**

Comment: @Ryan: glad it helps. Don't forget to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use logical or `||` like this:

```
$('#venetie').hide(); 
$('#CoachTravel').change(function(){
        if($('#CoachTravel').val() == '20 Fruit' ||  $('#CoachTravel').val() == '30 Cars') {
            $('#venetie').show(); 
        } else {
            $('#venetie').hide(); 
        } 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#CoachTravel').change(function(){
      if($('#CoachTravel').val() == '20 Fruit' || $('#CoachTravel').val() == '20 Fruit' ) {
         $('#venetie').show(); 
       } else {
          $('#venetie').hide(); 
      } 
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `if` condition to:

```
if( $.inArray($('#CoachTravel').val(), ['20 Fruit', '30 Cars']) > -1)
```

This checks if the value of `$('#CoachTravel')` is in the array `['20 Fruit', '30 Cars']` by using the function `inArray`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#venetie').hide(); 
$('#CoachTravel').change(function(){
  var Select_value = $('#CoachTravel').val();
  if(Select_value == '20 Fruit' ||  Select_value == '30 Cars') {
      $('#venetie').show(); 
  } else {
      $('#venetie').hide(); 
} 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="bestemming" id="CoachTravel" class="form-control select" >
<option value="10 Glasses" >10 Glasses</option>
<option value="20 Fruit" >20 Fruit</option>
<option value="30 Cars" >30 Cars</option>
</select>
<div class="form-group" id="venetie" >
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="radio">
<label for="radio">Ja </label>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="radio">Nee</div>
```

Please check the code Using **OR** operator you can achieve your desired result.

Thanks